# Search/replace labels in specific messages (not the whole thread) with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am working in Gmail with conversation view Off and I need to search for specific messages with 'Oldlabel' and I want only to change the labels of these specific messages with Google script to 'Newlabel'.

I now can only manage to find label names of messages and get all the messages of the whole thread, even if those individual messages don't contain this label. So they will be renamed to 'NewLabel' too and that is unwanted.

Here is the code I have untill now.

```
var oldlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Oldlabel");
var newlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Newlabel");
var threads = GmailApp.search("label:Oldlabel")
  for (var i=0; i< threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].removeLabel(oldlabel);
    threads[i].addLabel(newlabel);
  }
```

Comment: Where is your code and problem?

Comment: I rewrote my question now with the code I had untill sofar

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798530/gmailapp-add-label-to-specific-message-not-the-thread). It's exactly the same problem as yours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GmailApp - Add label to specific message, not the thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798530/gmailapp-add-label-to-specific-message-not-the-thread)

Comment: I am not sure if this is the solution. I am not concerning that I can add or remove a label to/from a specific message, but I need to know the message-id of the message(s) which I want to alter. I will rewrite my original question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Clarification here. Whether conversation view is on or off, or whether you know the `id`s of messages or not, with [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/) you **cannot** manipulate individual messages's label because [`GmailMessage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) class has no methods related to labels. Only [`GmailThread`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread) class has `getLabels()`. Also [`GmailLabel`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label) class has `addToThread()`, `addToThreads()`, etc, but it has no methods related to messages. If something is not in the official documentation, it does not exist.

So I've proposed you [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798530/gmailapp-add-label-to-specific-message-not-the-thread), which used [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/). I have not tested it myself, but it **looks like** working. Please try it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I have done another workaraound but that is also not perfect, but the best I can find now. Gmail and threads are for years a headache, that's for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.