# Google Apps Script - Changing label of individual email in Gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I want to change the label of an individual email programatically in gmail in a Google Script. I can't use the standard [GmailApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label) because it applies actions to the whole thread instead of an individual email. I've found a few examples of this being done with the Advanced Gmail API ([Search/replace labels in specific messages (not the whole thread) with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166342/search-replace-labels-in-specific-messages-not-the-whole-thread-with-google-ap#43232539)). But I've not had success with this. I keep getting the following error:

> Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only (line 5, file
>   "test")

Here is a code snippet that I've tried in Google Script's Editor:

```
function changeLabel() {
  var addLabel = '3to-smartsheetstest';
  var removeLabel = '3to-smartsheets';
  var msgId = '142b7c52e4cc4619';
  var msgLabel = Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
    'userId': 'me',
    'id': messageId,
    'resource':{
      'addLabelIds': [addlabel],
      'removeLabelIds': [removelabel]
    }
  })
}
```

[Google's resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#javascript) says to structure the parameters like this for javascript:

```
'userId': userId,
'id': messageId,
'addLabelIds': labelsToAdd,
'removeLabelIds': labelsToRemove
```

But it seems that it actually needs to be structured this way (clarified in a bug report here: [https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/312](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label)):

```
'userId': 'some email address',
'id': 'some message id',
'resource':{
    'addLabelIds': ['some label id'],
    'removeLabelIds': []
}
```

Either way I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Please modify the spelling of variables for `Gmail.Users.Messages.modify()`.

  - Modify `messageId` to `msgId`.
  - Modify `addlabel` to `addLabel`.
  - Modify `removelabel` to `removeLabel`.
- You can use `Gmail.Users.Messages.modify()` like `Gmail.Users.Messages.modify(resource, userId, id)`. You can see this by the autocomplete of the script editor.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var msgLabel = Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
  'userId': 'me',
  'id': messageId,
  'resource':{
    'addLabelIds': [addlabel],
    'removeLabelIds': [removelabel]
  }
})
```

To:

```
var msgLabel = Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({
  'addLabelIds': [addLabel],
  'removeLabelIds': [removeLabel]
}, 'me', msgId);
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that Gmail API is enabled at Advanced Google Services and API console.

#### Reference:

- [Using autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#using_autocomplete)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You caught a few errors in my pseudo code, thanks! I realized that my problem all along was that I was using label 'names' instead of label 'IDs'. So, I'll accept your answer because you caught some errors.

Comment: For reference to others, here is gs code for getting a list of all labels in your gmail account: 
`function listLabels() {
  var labels = Gmail.Users.Labels.list('me');
  Logger.log(labels);
}`

Comment: @Vanderling Thank you for replying and adding more information. I'm glad your issue was solved.