# how to label and check only one message ( Gmail email) in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I want my Google script to parse all emails **within a label**. But just **once**. The emails come from my bank. They store transaction details. Because I use thread conversation view I worry that the script will either - process one message more than once or miss a message in a case I mark the thread with a label let's say "done" once the email message was processed.

The transaction details are coming with the same subject, so all of them will be part of one thread.
I do not want to store message ID or something like outside Google Script.

Could you think of any solution?

I was thinking that I can add email ID to the thread but the I would end up with too many labels.

I might be able to use Gmail API as suggested here

- [GmailApp - Add label to specific message, not the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798530/gmailapp-add-label-to-specific-message-not-the-thread) and
- [Google Apps Script - Changing label of individual email in Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270973/google-apps-script-changing-label-of-individual-email-in-gmail)

but I do not know how to check if a particular message got specific label.

Comment: Do you use star for anything else?

Comment: @Cooper, I do use stars for quick access of very important emails but I thought of using starts. Once the thread is fully processed I might remove the stars.

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? About `I do not know how to check if a particular message got specific label.`, in this case, you want to retrieve the label from a message?

Comment: my goal is to process all emails but to make sure that every single one is processed only once. When thinking how to accomplish I thought I might use labels. It seems to me that I can add a label to a message not the whole thread. Now I need to know how I can easily check of a message got particular label. Right now I need to know how to check if a message got label.

Answer (score 2):

### You can query for messages containing a certain label with [Gmail.Users.Messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) specifying the `id` of a label

Sample:

```js
  var starredMessages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {"labelIds":"Label_981438383934575828"}).messages;
  var starredIds = [];
  starredMessages.forEach(function(message){starredIds.push(message.id)});
```

- Once you have this, you can retrieve all inbox messages, push their ids into an array and filter them to remove the already labelled messages from the array:

```js
  var AllIds = [];
  var allMessages = GmailApp.getInboxThreads().forEach(function(thread){thread.getMessages().forEach(function(message){AllIds.push(message.getId())})}); 
  var filteredIds= AllIds.filter(function (id) { return starredIds.indexOf(id) == -1;});
```

- As a result, you obtain an array with message Ids that do not have the specified label (yet).
- Now, do with those messages what you desire, e.g. in a loop and subsequently add the label to them with e.g.

```js
filteredIds.forEach(function(id){Gmail.Users.Messages.modify({'addLabelIds': [LabelId]}, 'me', id)});
```

UPDATE

### Another way to retrieve messages without the label is with the query parameter `q`.

Thereby, the query should be specified as `-label:MY LABEL` :

```js
var NotStarredMessages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("me", {"q":"-label:MY LABEL"}).messages;
```

HOWEVER, KEEP IN MIND THAT IF ONE MESSAGE OF A THREAD HAS THE LABEL, THIS SECOND METHOD WILL NOT EXCLUDE ALL MESSAGES OF THE CORRESPONDING THREAD FROM THE LIST.

So in your case the second method is not recommended.

Comment: this looks like what I need. So this part `var filteredIds= AllIds.filter(function (id) { return starredIds.indexOf(id) == -1;});` removes labelled messages (starred ones) from the array?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does!

Comment: I was thinking and that is why I created this question if there is a easier way how to find whether a particular post got a label. If not then I got a solution :-)

Comment: It might be faster to do it with a query, I will update my answer to show how.

Comment: so the update .. using q will return a thread not messages?

Comment: It will return messages (and messageIds), but the query condition seems to apply for the whole thread, so in your case, I would say it does not return you reliably all the correct messages and thus you need to use the first option (even it involves more steps).